# After I display all the elements in a database, how do I rearrange them?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a textbox and a button that puts whatever you just typed into a database, then I have this to display all those things, along with a delete button and a "top" button

```
<?php
$resultset2 = $db3->query('SELECT * FROM ask');
if($resultset2->num_rows != 0) {
    while ($rows = $resultset2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $question_enter = $rows['question'];
    $id = $rows['id'];
        echo "<form action='' method='post'><input type='hidden' value='".$id."' 
        name='the_id'><div><p>$question_enter<input type='submit' value='Delete' 
        name='deletedefaultnote'><input type='submit' value='Top' name='putontop'>
        </p></div></form>";
    }
} else {
    echo 'no results.';
}
?>
```

I have the delete button working, but I can't figure out how to get the "top" button to put an element on the top of the list that's being displayed. How should I do this?

If it's relevant, say item1 and item2 are on the bottom of a long list, if I put item1 on top of the list, then put item2 on top, item2 would be on top and item1 would be second on the list. I don't want the elements to return to their original position if something else goes on top.

Comment: Maybe you can add a field in your database with a position integer, and when you clic on "top" button, it will update the row position to 1 and the other to a lower position ? So after that, you make a : `SELECT .... FROM ask ORDER BY position ASC`

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to get the "top" button to function.

Comment: When trying to sort items (rows) in a table [jquery sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) is your best friend

Comment: @Kuya as I understand the question he/she wants to store the new ordering into the database. So the real question is "howto unshift and splice db result rows for a new ordering and persist them effectivly".

Comment: @TobiasJ with jquery sortable

Comment: @Kuya this would be the front-end but to persist the data effectively it got nothing to do with jQuery sortable nor frondend.

Answer (score -2):

To store the new ordering into database you have to update all positions. One simple approach would be to use a "position" column like sym mentioned.

With an `position-column beginning with 1 (0 is the "guardian")` you could then
update the `"new top" item and set the position to 0 (guardian)` after that you would have to `update ALL items/rows and set the position to old_position+1`.

As you can see this approach is heavy on queries so I would recommend not to update the table every time you click on your "top" button and instead order the items on frontend with something like jQuery (what Kuya) said and after you're done re-ordering your list save it in one big request with the method explained above.

UPDATE: To update the rows in your database you can also use a single query when so following conditions are met:

1. column position starts at 1 and is NOT unique
2. the new top position item's position was set to 0

Then you can simply do `UPDATE tablename SET position = position + 1`. The database will then automatically increment all position values (and position 0, the guardian will be available again).

Comment: The jquery ui sortable re-orders/sorts/re-arranges (whatever term you choose) AND updates all shifts to the affected rows in the database with one simple drag-n-drop movement. It can't get any easier than that. Please take a look at the link I provided. It might help you understand better what the jquery ui sortable is.

Comment: then tell us how it update the affected rows in the database without having information of the given database. The link you provided only affects DOM not persistent storages. My answer is correct to the purpose so downvoting just because you think you're answer is better is a childish behaviour which doesn't belong to SO

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is completely incorrect. I'm just saying there are easier ways of doing things. And I'm trying to help you understand as well. We are all here to learn from each other. I learn new things every day on SO. You ask, _"tell us how it update the affected rows in the database"_ (please see my updated answer above for that explanation) _"without having information of the given database"_. You do have the information. You got it when you did your sql query to display the list. You have the "id" (primary key/unique id) of each item and you have the "order_id" of each item.